# MySQL show all date from entire a month

Tags: mysql, date

how can i show all date from entire a month, where month is parameter for query (for example month between 1 and 3) then output this query will show date from first date in january until last date on march. maybe preview like below.

```
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
..
..
2013-02-28
..
2013-03-31
```

have any idea for this?thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to **generate a list of all dates between two dates** you can do that with the help of tally (numbers) table. You can easily create one like this

```
CREATE TABLE tally (n int not null primary key);

INSERT INTO tally
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + 1 n
  FROM 
 (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
ORDER BY n;
```

Now to create a list of all dates between the first of January and the last day of March you can do this

```
SELECT '2013-01-01' + INTERVAL t.n - 1 DAY day
  FROM tally t
 WHERE t.n <= DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY('2013-03-01'), '2013-01-01') + 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39bfb1/5)** demo

Comment: it's still create table? is there any solution if i don't need create table, maybe like derived table or something temporary data, not physic on DB?

Comment: thanks @peterm, i'm really apreciate it, but it's still cannot solve my problem, maybe there's no any way except must create table..thanks

Comment: agree with @empugandring. I just don't think need to create the table. It just seems not appropriate

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a table with number of entries greater than the number of dates that you need, then you can use this:

```
SELECT adddate('2013-01-01', @rownum := @rownum + 1) dt FROM my_table
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := -1) r
LIMIT 31;
```

Choose a small table for *my_table*. If *my_table* contains too many entries, use limit to make it faster.

The basis of this is using a counter like rownum that autoincrements itself. A more complex query with filtering using date functions:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT adddate('2013-01-01', @rownum := @rownum + 1) dt FROM my_table
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := -1) r LIMIT 1000) temp
WHERE MONTH(dt) = 1 AND YEAR(dt) = 2015;
```

Answer (score 2):

As example, for december 2019:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT('2019-12-',n)),'%Y-%m-%d') as Date from (
        select (((b4.0 << 1 | b3.0) << 1 | b2.0) << 1 | b1.0) << 1 | b0.0 as n
                from  (select 0 union all select 1) as b0,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b1,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b2,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b3,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b4 ) t
        where n > 0 and n <= day(last_day('2019-12-01'))
```

It produces the following result:

```
+------------+
| Date       |
+------------+
| 2019-12-01 |
| 2019-12-02 |
| 2019-12-03 |
| 2019-12-04 |
| 2019-12-05 |
| 2019-12-06 |
| 2019-12-07 |
| 2019-12-08 |
| 2019-12-09 |
| 2019-12-10 |
| 2019-12-11 |
| 2019-12-12 |
| 2019-12-13 |
| 2019-12-14 |
| 2019-12-15 |
| 2019-12-16 |
| 2019-12-17 |
| 2019-12-18 |
| 2019-12-19 |
| 2019-12-20 |
| 2019-12-21 |
| 2019-12-22 |
| 2019-12-23 |
| 2019-12-24 |
| 2019-12-25 |
| 2019-12-26 |
| 2019-12-27 |
| 2019-12-28 |
| 2019-12-29 |
| 2019-12-30 |
| 2019-12-31 |
+------------+
31 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tweaked [Brent Frere's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682584/1873567) to automatically list all the days for the current month, with no hardcoding of the date:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(year(now()),'-',month(now()),'-',n)),'%Y-%m-%d') as Date from (
        select (((b4.0 << 1 | b3.0) << 1 | b2.0) << 1 | b1.0) << 1 | b0.0 as n
                from  (select 0 union all select 1) as b0,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b1,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b2,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b3,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b4 ) t
        where n > 0 and n <= day(last_day(now()))
order by Date
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to set the year and month using MySQL variables:

```
set @year = 2020, @month = 11;
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(@year,'-',@month,'-',n)),'%Y-%m-%d') as Date from (
        select (((b4.0 << 1 | b3.0) << 1 | b2.0) << 1 | b1.0) << 1 | b0.0 as n
                from  (select 0 union all select 1) as b0,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b1,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b2,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b3,
                      (select 0 union all select 1) as b4 ) t
        where n > 0 and n <= day(last_day(CONCAT(@year,'-',@month,'-',1)))
order by Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.2.2) can be used Recursive Common Table Expressions:

```
WITH RECURSIVE `days` AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS `day` UNION ALL SELECT `day` + 1 FROM `days` WHERE `day` < DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))
)
SELECT * FROM `days`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where month(`date`) between 1 and 3
```

And if you need it for a specific year you should add that

```
select * from your_table
where year(`date`) = 2013
and month(`date`) between 1 and 3
```

Comment: is there any function in mysql,because i want join this query with other table (like derived table) for employee attendance report where show all date for a month.

employee table      derived table/query  other_query
      |                    |              |
      V                    V              V
+----------------+-----------------+----------+
| employee_id    | Date            | Status   |
+----------------+-----------------+----------+
| 1001           | 2013-01-01      | A        |
+----------------+-----------------+----------+

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM table WHERE dateField between '2013-01-01' and '2013-03-31'
```